# MySQL ORDER BY if number in db

Tags: mysql, arrays

i have problem. In my DB i have column page_home which store an array of number 4,6,2...
I need to order my select with condition: if 6 in page_home, then 1, if not then 2.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  order by case 
              when page_home like '% 6,%' 
               or page_home like '%,6,%' 
               or page_home like '%,6 %' then 0
              else 1
           end desc
```

Comment: Your soulution is not working, it works correct only this way:

ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN page_home LIKE '%6%' THEN 0

but i think there will be problem with more digit numbers...

Comment: can you show your data and what you want like desired result ?

Comment: while im waiting for your data , i edited my answer , try it.